# Displaying video previews from various providers

Tags: javascript, video, youtube, prototypejs

My use case is kinda basic. According to the URL a user inputs, I want to have the good player displayed, that varies according to the input of course.

For instance, inputting http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rv5OwTiBEiQ would display the preview of the Youtube player. The same goes with Dailymotion, Yahoo!, Vimeo, Justin.tv, Myspace...

Do you know is any Javascript plugin does this ? Ideally, it'd be based on Prototype.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Youtube case, all you have to do is get the video id of the url and put this in the follow URL:

`http://img.youtube.com/vi/{video-id}/1.jpg`

Then you have the link to the youtube preview image!

Comment: thanks for the tip :)
in the example I input, the filenames go up to 3. Is that always the case of it depends on the video ?

Comment: I don't know what you mean with "got up to 3" but you get the preview images for all Youtube videos with this URL. If it ends with 0.jpg you get a big image, if it ends with 1.jpg you get a small one.

Comment: oops, sorry, I just meant it goes from 1.jpg to 3.jpg. After that, there is only a generic picture. I tried with only 2 different video IDs, tho.

Comment: for more information, check this: http://www.reelseo.com/youtube-thumbnail-image/